# Extract specifit pages and make new pdf from list of pdfs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, automation

I have been trying to get spacfic pages extract from each pdf and then merge all the extracted pdf in once.

I have list of pdfs

I am using `pdfrw` this library but getting error while extracting the pages

```py
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter
import os
files = [f for f in os.listdir(
    '.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.pdf')]

print(files)


for pdf in files:
    pages = PdfReader(pdf).pages
    parts = [(6, 7)]
    for part in parts:
        title = pdf.title().split('.')[0]
        outdata = PdfWriter(f'{title}_{part[0]}_.pdf')
        for pagenum in range(*part):
            outdata.addpage(pages[pagenum-1])
        outdata.write()
```

Please help if possible

```
raise PdfParseError('Invalid PDF header: %s' %
pdfrw.errors.PdfParseError: Invalid PDF header: '<!doctype html>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Manas,

One way to achieve your requirement is to use API. For example, consider following code snippet where it splits PDF from uploaded file.

```
import os
import requests # pip install requests

# The authentication key (API Key).
# Get your own by registering at https://app.pdf.co
API_KEY = "*********************************"

# Base URL for PDF.co Web API requests
BASE_URL = "https://api.pdf.co/v1"

# Source PDF file
SourceFile = ".\\sample.pdf"
# Comma-separated list of page numbers (or ranges) to process. Example: '1,3-5,7-'.
Pages = "1-2,3-"


def main(args = None):
    uploadedFileUrl = uploadFile(SourceFile)
    if (uploadedFileUrl != None):
        splitPDF(uploadedFileUrl)


def splitPDF(uploadedFileUrl):
    """Split PDF using PDF.co Web API"""

    # Prepare requests params as JSON
    # See documentation: https://apidocs.pdf.co
    parameters = {}
    parameters["pages"] = Pages
    parameters["url"] = uploadedFileUrl

    # Prepare URL for 'Split PDF' API request
    url = "{}/pdf/split".format(BASE_URL)

    # Execute request and get response as JSON
    response = requests.post(url, data=parameters, headers={ "x-api-key": API_KEY })
    if (response.status_code == 200):
        json = response.json()

        if json["error"] == False:

            # Download generated PNG files
            part = 1

            for resultFileUrl in json["urls"]:
                # Download Result File
                r = requests.get(resultFileUrl, stream=True)

                localFileUrl = f"Page{part}.pdf"

                if r.status_code == 200:
                    with open(localFileUrl, 'wb') as file:
                        for chunk in r:
                            file.write(chunk)
                    print(f"Result file saved as \"{localFileUrl}\" file.")
                else:
                    print(f"Request error: {response.status_code} {response.reason}")

                part = part + 1
        else:
            # Show service reported error
            print(json["message"])
    else:
        print(f"Request error: {response.status_code} {response.reason}")


def uploadFile(fileName):
    """Uploads file to the cloud"""
    
    # 1. RETRIEVE PRESIGNED URL TO UPLOAD FILE.

    # Prepare URL for 'Get Presigned URL' API request
    url = "{}/file/upload/get-presigned-url?contenttype=application/octet-stream&name={}".format(
        BASE_URL, os.path.basename(fileName))
    
    # Execute request and get response as JSON
    response = requests.get(url, headers={ "x-api-key": API_KEY })
    if (response.status_code == 200):
        json = response.json()
        
        if json["error"] == False:
            # URL to use for file upload
            uploadUrl = json["presignedUrl"]
            # URL for future reference
            uploadedFileUrl = json["url"]

            # 2. UPLOAD FILE TO CLOUD.
            with open(fileName, 'rb') as file:
                requests.put(uploadUrl, data=file, headers={ "x-api-key": API_KEY, "content-type": "application/octet-stream" })

            return uploadedFileUrl
        else:
            # Show service reported error
            print(json["message"])    
    else:
        print(f"Request error: {response.status_code} {response.reason}")

    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, to merge PDF file you can use similar to following code snippet.

```
import os
import requests # pip install requests

# The authentication key (API Key).
# Get your own by registering at https://app.pdf.co
API_KEY = "**********************************"

# Base URL for PDF.co Web API requests
BASE_URL = "https://api.pdf.co/v1"

# Source PDF files
SourceFile_1 = ".\\sample1.pdf"
SourceFile_2 = ".\\sample2.pdf"

# Destination PDF file name
DestinationFile = ".\\result.pdf"

def main(args = None):
    UploadedFileUrl_1 = uploadFile(SourceFile_1)
    UploadedFileUrl_2 = uploadFile(SourceFile_2)

    if (UploadedFileUrl_1 != None and UploadedFileUrl_2!= None):
        uploadedFileUrls = "{},{}".format(UploadedFileUrl_1, UploadedFileUrl_2)
        mergeFiles(uploadedFileUrls, DestinationFile)

def mergeFiles(uploadedFileUrls, destinationFile):
    """Perform Merge using PDF.co Web API"""

    # Prepare requests params as JSON
    # See documentation: https://apidocs.pdf.co
    parameters = {}
    parameters["name"] = os.path.basename(destinationFile)
    parameters["url"] = uploadedFileUrls

    # Prepare URL for 'Merge PDF' API request
    url = "{}/pdf/merge".format(BASE_URL)

    # Execute request and get response as JSON
    response = requests.post(url, data=parameters, headers={ "x-api-key": API_KEY })
    if (response.status_code == 200):
        json = response.json()

        if json["error"] == False:
            #  Get URL of result file
            resultFileUrl = json["url"]            
            # Download result file
            r = requests.get(resultFileUrl, stream=True)
            if (r.status_code == 200):
                with open(destinationFile, 'wb') as file:
                    for chunk in r:
                        file.write(chunk)
                print(f"Result file saved as \"{destinationFile}\" file.")
            else:
                print(f"Request error: {response.status_code} {response.reason}")
        else:
            # Show service reported error
            print(json["message"])
    else:
        print(f"Request error: {response.status_code} {response.reason}")


def uploadFile(fileName):
    """Uploads file to the cloud"""
    
    # 1. RETRIEVE PRESIGNED URL TO UPLOAD FILE.

    # Prepare URL for 'Get Presigned URL' API request
    url = "{}/file/upload/get-presigned-url?contenttype=application/octet-stream&name={}".format(
        BASE_URL, os.path.basename(fileName))
    
    # Execute request and get response as JSON
    response = requests.get(url, headers={ "x-api-key": API_KEY })
    if (response.status_code == 200):
        json = response.json()
        
        if json["error"] == False:
            # URL to use for file upload
            uploadUrl = json["presignedUrl"]
            # URL for future reference
            uploadedFileUrl = json["url"]

            # 2. UPLOAD FILE TO CLOUD.
            with open(fileName, 'rb') as file:
                requests.put(uploadUrl, data=file, headers={ "x-api-key": API_KEY, "content-type": "application/octet-stream" })

            return uploadedFileUrl
        else:
            # Show service reported error
            print(json["message"])    
    else:
        print(f"Request error: {response.status_code} {response.reason}")

    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this sample I am using pdf.co API. Refer to following links for more information.

https://apidocs.pdf.co/30-pdf-split, https://apidocs.pdf.co/31-pdf-merge

Thanks!